# Task.Factory.StartNew() in Data Method -- Pass this.Database?

Tags: c#, multithreading, closures

I'm trying to turn a stored procedure call, within a data method, to an async call. This is the original method:

```
public void InsertFoo(Foo foo)
{
    this.Database.SomeStoredProcedure(foo);
}
```

My first attempt was this:

```
public void InsertFoo(Foo foo)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        this.Database.SomeStoredProcedure(foo);
    });
}
```

However, I get a runtime error that this.Database is null. (this.Database is the L2S data context.)

Then I did some research and thought creating my own local copy would do it:

```
public void InsertFoo(Foo foo)
{
    MyDataContext db = this.Database;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        db.SomeStoredProcedure(foo);
    });
}
```

However, db is disposed before it actually gets used by the thread, resulting in another runtime error.

I simply want to pass this.Database into the threaded method. Is that possible? If so, how? this.Database is going to be destroyed when the method returns, because the class instance is gone, so I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: You need to create the context inside of the asynchronous task itself, because it can't depend on the state of variables in the parent thread which as you say will be destroyed.  Context instances are intended to be very lightweight so you can use Unit Of Work pattern, where you create a new instance every time you are doing a separate work item.

Comment: How do I create the context inside of the asynchronous task itself?

Comment: `MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext()`?

Comment: Ah, okay... create the context, not reference it. My bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob. As the InsertFoo method returns immediately, the containing object instance is available for collection, and hence when the calls is made to the database the database instance has been disposed.

e.g. If you are doing something like

```
using(var xx = new FooContainer()){

xx.Foo(foo);

}
```

Then your FooContainer will dispose before the async call within the foo method has executed.

I think you'd be better off calling InsertFoo asynchronously rather that making an async call from within that method.

e.g. Something on the lines of `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> xx.InsertFoo(foo))` and using a continuation on completion to tidy up your `xx` containing object.

Comment: I might just need to do that. I was hoping to avoid it due to complexities in the calling code...